# Can an alcohol oxidation to ketone happen with hydrogen peroxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

As far as I know, usually $\ce{CrO3}$ and $\ce{KMnO4}$ are used for this scope, but can other oxidizers such as $\ce{H2O2}$ be used?

Comment: Not directly but by the intermediacy of catalytic oxidants e.g. rhenium compunds.  https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ic9806784